# Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:6.0.1

Tags: android-studio

ERROR: Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:6.0.1.
Searched in the following locations:
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/6.0.1/gradle-6.0.1.pom
If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
Required by:
    project :
Add Google Maven repository and sync project
Open File

Comment: were u able to fix this issue?

Answer (score 4):

You need to add `google()` to your plugin repositories like so:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
    }
}
```